# Apply a function on columns of a matrix

Tags: r

I'm using a function ("myfunction") from an R library in this way:

```
 myfunction(obj1, obj2, obj3, c("Name1", "Name2"))
```

where "Name1" and "Name2" are two gene names. Instead of retrieving information about this two genes, I would like to retrieve information on many other genes that are stored in a file with 1000 columns and 100 rows (100 rows are 100 gene names).

In other words, suppose my file is named fl1000. For each column I would like the following code:

```
myfunction(obj1, obj2, obj3, fl1000[,1])
myfunction(obj1, obj2, obj3, fl1000[,2])
myfunction(obj1, obj2, obj3, fl1000[,3])
....
myfunction(obj1, obj2, obj3, fl1000[,1000])
```

Since it is impossible to do so manually, how this can be done in a more compact and fast way?

Comment: It is not clear what you have tried with apply.

Comment: The growing list of downvotes (mine is only the fourth) is due both to the lack of any code and from the lack of adequate problem description to support writing any code.

Comment: okkk, let me edit with the real case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function has four arguments - obj1, obj2, obj3, and an unnamed argument that seems to be vector of two names.  It's not clear what those first three objs are - they vectors, single elements, or what?

So the first problem seems to be in what way could you possibly run a function of this sort on a single column from your rectangle of data.  To get anything working with apply on that rectangle, you will need a function that takes as its input a single vector of 100 elements.  Clearyl myfunction() is not such a function as it currently stands.  However, if that vector can be fed in as eg obj1, and you just need to supply other things to be obj2 and obj3, it would be simple to adjust the function so it will work.  But unless we have more of an idea of what you are doing we couldn't help more.

*Edit (after question's edit)*

The question still doesn't quite make sense to me, as the function looks like it wants a vector of Name1 and Name2, and you now want to give it a row with 100 values (not just 2).

But putting that aside, perhaps you want:

```
apply(fl1000, 2, function(x){myfunction(obj1, obj2, obj3, x)})
```